# How to pass a value from javascript as a parameter to sql in pentaho

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-cde

SQL code:-

```
SELECT 
     CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(A, 1)), SUBSTRING(A, 2)) AS 'Service Center Name',
    CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(B, 1)), SUBSTRING(B, 2)) AS 'State',
     CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(C, 1)), SUBSTRING(C, 2)) AS 'Status'
       FROM
    (SELECT 
        LOWER(A.service_center_name) AS A,
        A.status AS C,
        LOWER(C.branch_name) AS 'B'
    FROM
        customers A
    INNER JOIN ascs B ON A.serv_cent_mob_no = B.contact_number
    INNER JOIN branches C ON B.branch_id = C.id
    GROUP BY A.service_center_name , A.status , C.branch_name) AS Issue
       WHERE B=${sqlcity};
```

External Javascript Code:-

```
var decode="tamilnadu";
```

I want to pass the variable "decode" to ${sqlcity}.

Is there any way?

Comment: Kindly help us to solve this problem.

Comment: I print the variable "decode" in a layout by using below code.                                                                              "   document.getElementById("city").innerHTML=decode;    "    But I am not able to pass that variable to ${sqlcity}. Have anybody knows the answer??

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like to pass the city information from javascript as a variable to the query, the javascript and query execution should be in two different transformations. 
Trans A: Handle the city information in javascript and set the value to the variable "sqlcity" and define the scope as required ("valid in the Parent Job").
Trans B: Using Table Input (Check "Replace variables in script" checkbox) with the above query you can extract results.

If you like to use the variable within the transformation, pass the variable in the Fields table of "Modified Java Script" and connect the Modified JS to Table Input and use the option "Insert data from step" and in query replace ${sqlcity} with "?".

Comment: To pass the value "decode", I used custom parameter and give name as "sqlcity". Is there any possibilities to pass this "decode" value to custom parameter in pentaho